# Heat transfer analysis of heated electric cooktop

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I would like to know how many hours a single burner electric cooktop to be heated at 440 ºC (electric power 1,200W/220V) to ignite papers(tissue) or vinyl wrappers put on the same shelf at same level with 5 cm distance from the cooktop in a room teperature of 10 ºC basis 30% humidity.
The cooktop has a dimension of 280 x 350 mm.
Please advise of the title of the papers on similar subject, if any.

With thanks and Kind Regards,

E.S.Kang

eskang55@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. There are altogether too many potential details to get anything like an accurate answer. What sort of air circulation is there? What shelf material? Exactly what sort of material are you considering igniting?

Far less work, and probably far more accurate, would be some experiments.

Set up a situation where starting a fire will not be dangerous. This might be something like a large empty parking area with good paving. Or a gravel covered area. Someplace where you can arrange that if something starts on fire it won't damage anything you care about, and won't spread to anything.

Set up a power supply. Be sure that power supply has an easy way you can turn it off if the experiment starts to go in unexpected ways.

Then do some measurements. Set up a shelf over a cooker similar to your target cooker. Possibly set up several shelves at different heights and see what the effect is. Maybe set different samples of different materials over the burner. If you have a GoPro or similar camera, set it up and take vids to record your results. It might make a good YouTube vid.

Comment: Sorry for my belated reply to your prompt advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my belated reply to your prompt advice due to my private engagements. I will attend the pleading tomorrow to defend my daughter for the fire assumed to have started at electric cooktop in the kitchen 36 hours after she left for trip. Insurance company filed a lawsuit for reason of so-called negligence of arguing that my daughter might have switched on electric cooktop before leaving the room which was incidence case so-called negligence of duty requested for  tenant of one-room apartment. I firmly believe that she locked the cooktop  but I have to prove that the cooktop was not in operating condition at the time of her departure by monthly electricity consumption measurement data and selfignition point of papers, cooktop temperature/wattage data, etc. That was why I posted my question for assistance.

Comment: I surmised something like this. A court is very much more likely to pay attention to careful experiments than to very theoretical calculations. Especially if you do the GoPro thing.